# Flutter Firestore - Catching exceptions when listening to data streams

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When fetching **all** documents of a collection from `Firestore` using the `get()` method, by default it won't throw an exception if there is no internet connection. Instead it looks up the cache and returns cached data. But sometimes you need to know whether a collection is actually currently empty **or** you just cannot connect to the database.

And for just fetching data there is a solution to that: the `GetOptions` parameter can be set to `Source.server`. That way an error will be thrown if the server cannot be reached.

Now I'm looking for an equivalent of this option for the `snapshots()` method that returns a `Stream` instead of just single data. So I need the stream to emit an error when it cannot connect to the server.

So:

```
await _firestore
        .collection('stuff')
        .where("someBool", isEqualTo: false)
        .get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server));
```

will throw a `FirebaseException` on bad connection, while:

```
_firestore
    .collection('stuff')
    .where("someBool", isEqualTo: false)
    .snapshots()
    .listen((snap) { ...  }, onError: (e) {
         //never called...
         debugPrint(e.toString());
     });
```

in this example I just can't find out.

Closest to a solution I got was checking on `snap.metadata.isFromCache` and throwing an exception when the value is `true`.
But this does not work reliably. False meaning the snapshot is guaranteed to be up to date with the server. But in some cases it is `true` even though it got a valid response from the server.

Edit: `isFromCache` property would be a solution if I filtered `someBool` locally instead of directly in the query.

```
_firestore
    .collection('stuff')
    .where("someBool", isEqualTo: false)
    .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true)
    .listen((snap) { 
         //`hasPendingWrites` is false in all these cases:
         //  1. changing a document's `someBool` field from `false` to `true` and vise versa
         //  2. requesting with server connection
         //  3. requesting without server connection
         debugPrint("snap metadata pendingWrites is: ${snap.metadata.hasPendingWrites}");
         if (snap.metadata.isFromCache) {
         //I thought data from cache is only used when there's trouble connecting to the server which is not the case:
         //
         //no internet connection will indeed cause this value to be true
         //but changing a document's `someBool` field from `false` to `true` however, will  cause it to be true, too
             debugPrint("metadata of this snap is from cache -> throwing NoInternetException");
             throw NoInternetException();
         }
     }, onError: (e) {
         //never called...
         debugPrint(e.toString());
     });
```

Edit: I have offline persistence disabled:

```
db.settings = const Settings(persistenceEnabled: false);
```

**Experiment: Updating a document's `someBool` field (directly from `Firestore Console`):**

*with internet:*

true to false:  `pendingWrites` is `false`,  `isFromCache` is `false`

false to true:  `pendingWrites` is `false`,  `isFromCache` is `true`

When just turning the internet off while the `Stream` is being listened to:

`pendingWrites` is `false`,  `isFromCache` is `true`

So the 'false to true' case with internet leads to a false positive using the `isFromCache` member.

Edit:

The documentation states:

> If you called [DocumentReference.snapshots] or [Query.snapshots] with
> `includeMetadataChanges` parameter set to `true` you will receive
> another snapshot with `isFomCache` equal to `false` once the client
> has received up-to-date data from the backend.

Now in this false positive case (setting the bool from `false` to `true`) the `Stream` fires twice:

- First time with `isFromCache`: `true`
- Second time (immediately after first time): `isFromCache`: `false`

So for some reason Firestore reads from the cache even though there is a connection to the server. So I can't rely on this property when it comes to throwing `NoInternetException`.

Comment: check `Stream.handleError` method

Comment: @pskink Did without success

Comment: so `handleError` callback is not called or what?

Comment: Correct, it is not called. I am simulating the bad connection by going into airplane mode for the request.

Comment: so it seems that your firebase stream doesn't throw any errors ;-(

Comment: Yea that's the issue..

Comment: Damn, I didn't notice that dude was writing about that. Deleted my answer. XD

Answer (score 3):

Firebase applications work even if your app temporarily loses its network connection. In addition, Firebase provides tools for persisting data locally, managing presence, and handling latency.

like as example you can check the internet connection like that,
**Detecting Connection State**

```
final connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(".info/connected");
connectedRef.onValue.listen((event) {
  final connected = event.snapshot.value as bool? ?? false;
  if (connected) {
    debugPrint("Connected.");
  } else {
    debugPrint("Not connected.");
  }
});
```

and also for more details, you can check out this link:-
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/offline-capabilities

and for particularly firestore you can follow this,

```
db
    .collection('stuff')
    .where("someBool", isEqualTo: false)
    .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true)
    .listen((querySnapshot) {
  for (var change in querySnapshot.docChanges) {
    if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.added) {
      final source =
          (querySnapshot.metadata.isFromCache) ? "local cache" : "server";

      print("Data fetched from $source}");
    }
  }
});
```

for more detail follow this link(for firestore):-
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#dart_2

Comment: `FirebaseDatabase` is not part of the `Firestore` library. From what I see in the docs this is part of the `Firebase Realtime Database`.

Comment: Ok, for firstore you can follow this link.https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#dart_1

Comment: I have also updated my answer

Comment: Yes I already tried using `isFromCache` (see my original question), but could not get reliable information (due to false positives)

Comment: @Lara You know that you can extract connected value in your app and read it inside Firestore `onSnapshot()` ?

Comment: @Mises Which connected value do you mean?

Comment: @Lara First code snippet in this answer you got connected value. `final connected = event.snapshot.value as bool? ?? false;`

Comment: Well I don't think there is a `value` property for a Firestore `QuerySnapshot`

Comment: @Lara Real Time database and Firestore are two different libraries and databases.

Comment: @Lara First code snippet in this answer is to Real Time Database and second one it to Firestore.

Comment: I get that. But the Firestore snipped is just reading `isFromCache` when a document is added. In my example I am not even adding documents.

Comment: @Lara Firestore is more expansive but if you want to you can always use get() instead of snapshoot. Get method always make a request to Firestore and don't take data from cache unless you set it up.

Comment: @Lara You need to extract connection variable out of first RTDB listener and use it in Firestore snapshoot.

Comment: Yea true but in my use case I need to listen to changes in realtime. Having a timer calling get() every seconds and I'm poor in a day.

Comment: extracting RTDB won't work reliably since those actions would not be atomic. Just like a connectivity listener would not work. Also: what if the user has a connection to RTDB server but the Firestore servers are down...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246933/discussion-between-mises-and-lara).

Answer (score 2):

In order to do what you want you have to:
First make sure that cache is disabled and cleared:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings =
    Settings(persistenceEnabled: false);

await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();
```

Now, when you try to access anything without network connection, you should get an empty snapshot with "isFromCache" equal to true. Unfortunately there is no error in this case. It is just the way  it is designed.

Hope I helped.

Comment: As stated in my original question I already am getting `isFromCache` equal to true without a connection. The problem is that there a cases where this also happens with a connection.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're describing is exactly what Firestore developers wanted, and indeed it has its drawbacks..

The only thing I'd add to your current solution would be a connectivity check using either something like [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) or [internet_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker)

```
final _hasConnection = await yourConnectivityProvider.isConnected();

_firestore
    .collection('stuff')
    .where("someBool", isEqualTo: false)
    .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true)
    .listen((snap) { 
         //`hasPendingWrites` is false in all these cases:
         //  1. changing a document's `someBool` field from `false` to `true` and vise versa
         //  2. requesting with server connection
         //  3. requesting without server connection
         debugPrint("snap metadata pendingWrites is: ${snap.metadata.hasPendingWrites}");
         if (snap.metadata.isFromCache) {
         //I thought data from cache is only used when there's trouble connecting to the server which is not the case:
         //
         //no internet connection will indeed cause this value to be true
         //but changing a document's `someBool` field from `false` to `true` however, will  cause it to be true, too
             if (!_hasConnection) {
                 debugPrint("metadata of this snap is from cache -> throwing NoInternetException");
                 throw NoInternetException();
              }
         }
     }, onError: (e) {
         //never called...
         debugPrint(e.toString());
     });
```

**connectivity_plus** will only detect if the device has it's Wifi/4G ON, but it's pretty light and won't affect the battery.
**internet_connection_checker** will give you a 'real' info about the connectivity, but it has to query a server to get this info.

Will it work 100% of the time ? Probably not.
There are a few use-cases where, even with this 'security', you may get false positives (or even false-negatives, which is even worst).

Comment: Unfortunately, in my app I need a bullet proof solution. Until they patch a solution (such as a snapshots() parameter that allows exception throwing) I'm gonna have to go with a combination of `isFromCache`  and filtering on device (instead of `.where(...)`)

Comment: Did you open an Issue on their Github ? Would gladly Subscribe to your request and follow it up

Comment: Yes, a friend of mine who is working with me on this opened an issue https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9261

Answer (score 1):

See my ticket i opened in June: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8961

As you can see in the last entry i've opened a feature request at Firebase support which asks for adding the GetOptions parameter in Query.snapshots and DocReference.snaphots calls.

Also you could have a look at the [Nimbostratus](https://pub.dev/packages/nimbostratus) package which tries to overcome the current limitations in Firestore.